# electron Js ,Drag-drop, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, electron

I am new to Electron Framework. I'm trying to develop desktop application using Electron Framework. I want to implement an use case like team viewer  on the left side where I have local directories and on the right side I have network directories. I want to copy a file or folder from local to network using drag and drop functionality. How should i do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I put together a quick example. You will have to modify that, because it only works for moving files on the same drive.

Here is my index.html with two divs to test the drag control:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sourceDrive" class="drive" ondrop="dropOnSource(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="destinationDrive" class="drive" ondrop="dropOnDestination(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body>
```

And the respective app.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

function loadFiles(){
    ipc.send("loadFiles");
}
loadFiles();

ipc.on('sourceFiles', (ev, args) => {
    document.querySelector("#sourceDrive").innerHTML = "";
    args.forEach(file => { 
        document.querySelector("#sourceDrive").innerHTML += '<div id="'+file+'" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">'+file+'</div>';
    });
})
ipc.on('destinationFiles', (ev, args) => {
    document.querySelector("#destinationDrive").innerHTML = "";
    args.forEach(file => { 
        document.querySelector("#destinationDrive").innerHTML += '<div id="'+file+'" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">'+file+'</div>';
    });
})

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function dropOnSource(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ipc.send('moveToSource', data);
    loadFiles();
}
function dropOnDestination(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ipc.send('moveToDestination', data);
    loadFiles();
}
```

And here is the main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const ipc = electron.ipcMain;
const fs = require("fs");

let mainWindow;

const sourcePath = "fileSource";
const destinationPath = "fileDestination";

app.on('ready', _ => {
    console.log("App running");

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/ui/index.html');

    ipc.on("loadFiles", (event, arg) => {
        var fileStackSource = [];
        fs.readdirSync(sourcePath).forEach(file => {
            fileStackSource.push(file);
        });
        var fileStackDestination = [];
        fs.readdirSync(destinationPath).forEach(file => {
            fileStackDestination.push(file);
        });
        mainWindow.webContents.send('sourceFiles', fileStackSource);
        mainWindow.webContents.send('destinationFiles', fileStackDestination);
    });

    ipc.on('moveToSource', (event, arg) => {
        console.log("moving " + arg + " from " + destinationPath + " to " + sourcePath);
        fs.renameSync(destinationPath + "/" + arg, sourcePath + "/" + arg);
    });
    ipc.on('moveToDestination', (event, arg) => {
        console.log("moving " + arg + " from " + sourcePath + " to " + destinationPath);
        fs.renameSync(sourcePath + "/" + arg, destinationPath + "/" + arg);
    });
});
```

My directory looks as follows:

- main.js
- ui

-- index.html

-- app.js

- fileSource
- fileDestination

This should help you to understand the basics of what you are planning to do. If you are still uncertain about the basics of electron, I'd recommend you start with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Electron.

For your drag&drop logic, you could try this: [Drag&Drop Electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop)
or just use any html/js drag&drop library if you only need it inside of one window.

You can access the files using node modules, in this case you could use the file system module [Node FS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: "For your drag&drop logic, you could try this: Drag&Drop Electron or just use any html/js drag&drop library if you only need it inside of one window." how to implement?

Comment: Do you want two BrowserWindows and drag from one to another or one Window and drag inside of that?

Comment: Yes more or less like a team viewer.i want to drag from one div in which i have local directory and in another div has the linux directory.i just want to drag a file or folder from local to the network.drag and drop happens but the copying of file doesn't happen.

Comment: Please find the render.js link
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wRb091NLOBtmm20v7YqcDNfy8EKyxbVtLUYO2AxEGNk/edit

main.html
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Wcp2n7-MC9urUC5woowNu4rxZOkaTJ3T0IziSBMHZGo/edit

Comment: You need to send a message to your main.js using IPCRenderer, listen for that message in your main.js and copy the file if that message is received. You would probably send said message in your drop function. You need to pass the id or the complete path as an argument.

Comment: can you help me with any sample code which meets my requirement?

Comment: I posted a new answer since it is a bit longer

Comment: I tried your code but,i see a white screen in the browser window and no errors in the console.please can you create plunker and  share the link. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create any files inside of the two folders? The window will only render the files, so it will remain empty if there are no files.

Comment: Thank you.that worked.But how to loop system directories and perform the same operation like transfer of files.

Comment: This would be out of scope of your initial question. Additionally, since the answer below answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer, so others will be able to see it. Good luck with your project!